# Relation between $S_{n-1}$ , $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$

Tags: quadratics

We know $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ are roots of $ax^2+bx+c = 0 $.

also $S_{n-1} = \alpha^{n-1} + \beta^{n-1}$ , $S_{n} = \alpha^{n} + \beta^{n}$ and $S_{n+1} = \alpha^{n+1} + \beta^{n+1}$.

How we can find relation between $S_{n-1}$ , $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ ?

Note : We know that relation has $a$ , $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Short answer: write all three as a linear combination of $\alpha^{n-1}$ and $\beta^{n-1}$. You now have three vectors in a two-dimensional space.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: See my answer for the simplest proof

Comment: So , can we conclude this relation for all polynomials ? $$aS_n + bS_{n-1} + cS_{n-2} + ... + z = 0 $$ if $$ S_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n + .... + \gamma^n , S_{n-1} = \alpha^n-1 + \beta^n-1 + .... + \gamma^n-1

Comment: That would be true.

Comment: How we can prove it in general with inductive ?

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\alpha^{n} + \beta^{n}=(\alpha + \beta)(\alpha^{n-1} + \beta^{n-1})-\alpha\beta\cdot(\alpha^{n-2} + \beta^{n-2})$$

Now using the relation between the coefficients of a quadratic equation and its roots, we get that

$$S_n=-\frac{b}{a}S_{n-1}-\frac{c}{a}S_{n-2}$$

Or, in other words, we can write that $$S_{n+1}=-\frac{b}{a}S_{n}-\frac{c}{a}S_{n-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy the equation:
$ax^2+bx+c=0$
Thus they satisfy the following equation by multiplying with $x^{n-1}$:

$ax^{n+1}+bx^n+cx^{n-1}=0$

Thus:

$a\alpha^{n+1}+b\alpha^n+c\alpha^{n-1}=0$

$a\beta^{n+1}+b\beta^n+c\beta^{n-1}=0$

And by addition:

$aS_{n+1}+bS_n+cS_{n-1}=0$

It generalizes trivially to any polynomial of degree $\geq 2$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$S_{n}\cdot(\alpha+\beta)=(\alpha^n+\beta^n)\cdot(\alpha+\beta)=\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}+\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})
=S^{n+1}+\alpha\beta S^{n-1}.$$
Note also that 
$$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{b}{a}\mbox{ and }\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}.$$
Combining all these, we find the required relation.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
  \alpha^n+\beta^n &=
  (\alpha+\beta)(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})-
  \alpha \beta (\alpha^{n-2}+\beta^{n-2}) \\
  &= (\alpha+\beta) S_{n-1}-\alpha \beta S_{n-2} \\
  S_{n} &= -\frac{b}{a}S_{n-1}-\frac{c}{a}S_{n-2}
\end{align*}